# Optimize C compiles: removed unreferenced parts on-the-fly

Tags: c, compilation, linker, optimization

We're facing an interesting topic. Lets say we have a special-functions.c file, basically a library. 
We need to optimize the code as getting rid of all unused/unreferenced functions during the build process on-the-fly. 
I'm not searching for generally unused (dead) code: some parts will be "dead" in case of compiling to one of the architectures, but it's going to be used in an other architecture build.

Does anybody knows of flags, tools, methods, tricks to do this?
The compiler is standard gcc with ansi 99 C code.

EDIT
I know, this is mainly the part of the linker, but using gcc, the process is not really split into two parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://embeddedfreak.wordpress.com/2009/02/10/removing-unused-functionsdead-codes-with-gccgnu-ld/ :

> - Compile with `-fdata-sections` to keep the data in separate data
>     sections and `-ffunction-sections` to keep functions in separate
>     sections, so they (data and functions) can be discarded if unused.
> - Link with `--gc-sections` to remove unused sections.

For example:

```
gcc -Os -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections test.c -o test -Wl,--gc-sections
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that a recent GCC (i.e. **4.6**) should do that if you compile and *link* with the `-flto` flag (link time optimization). I would imagine that having `hidden` or `internal` [visibility](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) should be relevant (at least for non-static functions).

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, the GNU binary utils (ld, in this case) already remove unusesd references on static link